# How to use Url.Action to pass multiple Parameters to Route

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, url.action

I'm just learning MVC and am trying to create a SEO page title, therefore I'm sending an ID for the controller but also the page slug for the SEO.

I want to see Recipe/Details/18/foobar

but the below code returns

Results/Name/18?name=foobar

I presume its an issue with my custom Route but from all mt Research I think I'm doing it correctly.  Any assistance is appreciated.

**_PartialView**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Recipe", new {id = Recipe.ID, name = Recipe.Slug}, null)">
```

**RouteConfig**

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Recipe",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}",
            defaults: new {
                            controller = "Recipe",
                            action = "Details",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                            name = UrlParameter.Optional
                            }
        );
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your custom routes before the default one. They are processed in order, so in your case the mvc uses the default route.

Regards,
Mihail

Comment: My only issue is now my Default route no longer fires when I load my project without specifying Home/Index in the url ?

Comment: I finally fixed it by adding a constraint to my new Route.  again, thx for your help.